# SQL Pivot Table w/ and w/o Distinct Same Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot

I am trying to get the result of customer visit count by location using a pivot table but count(distinct customer_id) and count(customer_id) returning the same result. What should I do? Should I write another subquery only for that part?

```
select Locationname as 'Location',[2020],[2019],[2018],[2017],[2016],[2015],[2014],[2013],[2012],[2011],[2010]
from (select year(date_when) [date_when2],Locationname ,count(distinct customer_id) [cst_id] from record
group by date_when,Locationname) as aws

PIVOT(
    count([cst_id]) 
    FOR [date_when2] IN (
        [2020],
        [2019],
        [2018],
        [2017],
        [2016],
        [2015],
        [2014],
        [2013],
        [2012],
        [2011],
        [2010]  
        )
) AS pivot_table
```

Edit as Requested:
This is the current result of the query, however I want to see unique customer count and distinct makes no difference.

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select Locationname as'Location,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2020 then customer_id end) as custs_2020,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2019 then customer_id end) as custs_2019,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2018 then customer_id end) as custs_2018,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2017 then customer_id end) as custs_2017,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2016 then customer_id end) as custs_2016,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2019 then customer_id end) as custs_2015,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2015 then customer_id end) as custs_2014,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2014 then customer_id) as custs_2013,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2013 then customer_id end) as custs_2012,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2012 then customer_id end) as custs_2011,
       count(distinct case when year(date_when) = 2011 then customer_id end) as custs_2010
from record
group by Locationname;
```

I'm not a fan of `pivot` syntax.  It is finicky, non-standard, hard to follow (the "subquery" has to be just right to work with the outer query), and not very generalizable.

Comment: Same here but for my future queries I need to learn pivot table comprehensively so I need to understand why distinct is not working properly. Thank you so much for this query but I need to do it with pivot table :(

Comment: A Cross Tab is a form of piviting, @Anil . The benefit, however, is that it's transferable to other RDBMS and it's more flexible